# pythonanywhere | Python

Tags: python, файлы, telebot, pythonanywhere

Пытаюсь с облака отправить файл для скачивания в Телебот. Файл cdr.

```py
import telebot

token = "мой токен"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['doc'])
def get_user_document(message):
    bot.send_document(message.chat.id, document='https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/rx1sad11funfhp7775mno/.cdr?rlkey=n4c9bbg4hute39wfn3tpkqyso&dl=0', caption='Ваш заказ')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified

Comment: Переделала на zip файл, но все равно бот не отправляет:

Comment: '@bot.message_handler(commands=['doc'])
def get_user_document(message):
    bot.send_document(message.chat.id, document='https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/hjam9kfwefgxa19gw8u74/vechalka.zip?rlkey=o30dve1imvcqr2yd3q3u9tejh&dl=0', caption='Ваш заказ')'